# Better Swift array sorting method?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I'm trying to sort an int array inside of Swift from greatest to least. The code I used is:

```
Array(data.keys).sorted(by: { $0 > $1 })
```

The array given is an array with integers 1 through 1,000. The results are:

```
999, 998, 997 ... 991, 990, 99, 989 ... 802, 801, 800, 80, 8, 799, 798 ...
```

The results I want are:

```
999, 998, 997 ... 991, 990, 989 ... 802, 801, 800, 799, 798 ...
```

Comment: You don't have an array of integers. You have an array of strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dictionary keys are strings not integers. You can sort them comparing those keys using numeric options as follow:

```
let sorted = data.keys.sorted { 
    $0.compare($1, options: .numeric) == .orderedDescending 
}
```

Comment: How does this compare (performance-wise) to mapping to int first, then sorting? (Assuming an `[Int]` is acceptable final result type)

Comment: Gosh I feel dumb, sorry for wasting your time haha

Answer (score -2):

The sort is calculating based on ASCII String Values,

Type Coersion to Int....

Comment: Swift doesn't coerce Strings/Characters to ASCII (for one, because they're utf encoded (8/16/32, I don't remember), and it doesn't do almost any coercions implicitly, in general.

Comment: Poor use of language by me... I was just pointing out that the sort was occurring based on String/character rather than Int sort which is what the correct solution does....